# How to delete all comments from datasource in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I know how to delete a comment by position, but how do you delete all comments from a datasource?

I want to delete it when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

To delete all of the data in a table, you need to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
```

Comment: I was use this tutorial [http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial] there not include table, or I something not understand?

Comment: Basically, you have to change table_name to the appropriate name for the table. Without knowing what that is, I can't possible give you the exact answer, and I'm not going to go digging to find it...

Answer (score 2):

You should use `TRUNCATE`

```
TRUNCATE TABLE comments_table
```

Comment: sqlite does not support TRUNCATE statement. try it first

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is

```
DELETE FROM mytable
```

**Do NOT use `*` after DELETE** - it will cause syntax error!

Using `TRUNCATE mytable` would have been tempting, but unfortunately **SQLite does NOT support** `TRUNCATE`.

However, SQLite does provide [special optimization provision](http://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) for `DELETE FROM` statement. Namely, if `WHERE` clause was not specified (like in our case), then all space taken by rows in table is reclaimed very quickly, so behaviour is similar to true `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: What in this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial tutorial is "mytable".